# Is this the correct way to return this data using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq statement, however I'm not convinced its the best way of achieving the goal (but I'm not sure):

```
return
    Buyer.Where(x =>
        x.OperatingCalendar.BankHolidays.Any(y => y.OccursOn == today.Date)) ??
        Buyer.Where(x =>
            x.OperatingCalendar.DayOfWeek.DayID == (int)today.DayOfWeek);
```

The idea is to query `Buyer.OperatingCalendar` to find a row indicating that today a public holiday, and if its not a public holiday a row indicating the day of week. Some buyers do not have any rows.

The key is that `OperatingCalendar` can potentially contain a row for both scenarios for each buyer, but if a public holiday exists it must override day of the week. If no rows exist Buyer would return null.

Can't use OR - due to unique data requirements. The diagram below should explain the situation.

[image]

Comment: Since you are returning Buyer in either case don't you just need to see if one or the other is true?  Why does it matter the BankHolidays check is first?  The buyer object will contain both collections of bankholidats and dayofweek.

Comment: Using `??` here will not work since `Where` never returns `null`.

Comment: I don't think you're expression will do what you want - .Where returns an enumerable list which will be empty and therefore not null if there are no items. Therefore your ?? expression will never pick the second option. You need to do a .FirstOrDefault() on each expression.

Comment: It might also be tidier to have the check in an extension method on DateTime, supplying a specific custom calendar type if the Buyers are in areas with different public holidays.

Comment: is `BankHolidays` collection of same type as `DayOfWeek`?

Answer (score 2):

`Where` will never return `null` so the [?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173224.aspx) is useless here. Assuming you only want to ever pull a single result anyway then you should use [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb359429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of `Where`, this should allow you to use `??` correctly

```
return 
    Buyer.SingleOrDefault(x => 
        x.OperatingCalendar.BankHolidays.Any(y => y.OccursOn == today.Date)) ??
    Buyer.SingleOrDefault(x => 
        x.OperatingCalendar.DayOfWeek.DayID == (int)today.DayOfWeek);
```

You can, however, do this in one query which would save you an extra trip to the DB

```
return Buyer.SingleOrDefault(x => 
    x.OperatingCalendar.BankHolidays.Any(y => y.OccursOn == today.Date) || 
    x.OperatingCalendar.DayOfWeek.DayID == (int)today.DayOfWeek)
```

Comment: This second variant won't work. There are other columns that relate to the Buyer/OperatingCalenderID - such as opening and closing times. It's therefore imperitive that the correct OperatingCalendarID is found.

Comment: @dotnetnoob I can only answer the question based on the information given and, in this scenario, the second example is functionally equivalent to the first so it wouldn't make sense that the first variant works but the second wouldn't.

Comment: The use of SingleOrDefault also fails. I've attached the DB schema in order to provide more info.

Comment: I think you need `x.OperatingCalendar.BankHolidays.FirstOrDefault(...)`.

Comment: @GertArnold if I understand the OP correctly they want to return a single `Buyer` if the date falls on a bank holiday, so I think `Any` is correct here.

Comment: Yeah, it looks OK. But apparently, the OP wasn't convinced. @dotnetnoob can you elaborate as to *how* it fails?

Comment: If you look at the schema above, you will notice that BuyerNonWorkingtime isn't unique - it's uniqueness includes OperatingCalendar. To give you a real world example, OperatingCalendar contains entries for days/dates that the buyer is closed, i.e. Sat, Sun 25/12/2014 - each one of these has a OperatingCalendarID. I want to return all the buyers that have an OperatingCalendarID = today (some may have 1, some 2 and some 0). I need to identify the correct OperatingCalendarID in addition to the buyer because of the Opening/Closing times in the buyer table.

Comment: @GertArnold - I've added a comment, that may help clarify.

Comment: @James -  - I've added a comment, that may help clarify.

Comment: @dotnetnoob couldn't that just be a local query against the `OperatingCalendar` property of the `Buyer` though? The query above is about getting the right `Buyer` - if you need more context to that i.e. exactly which `BankHoliday` / `DayOfWeek` matched, you could do this as a sub-request. Or am I missing something? Is `OperatingCalendar` actually a list of calendars?

Comment: @James - in simple terms, today can be Christmas Day, or it can simply be a Thursday. It's at least one of those and possibly both. A buyer might not work Thursdays, however, he might also not work on Christmas day. He might work Thursdays, but not Christmas Day. The NonWorking table will including buyers, and the ID linking to the OperatingCalendar for all days/dates that they don't work. So I need to find the 1 or 2 ID's in the OperatingCalendar that relate to today, and check whether there are any buyers with those ID's.